# В чём ошибка при вызове функции из С++ в Java?

Tags: java, c++

Вызываю функцию С++ из библиотеки .dll

```
public class Test {

    public native long Connect ();  

    static{
        System.loadLibrary("spsdksw");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Test t = new Test ();
        System.out.println(t.Connect());
    }

}
```

но компилятор выдаёт ошибку:

> ```
> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Test.Connect()J
> at Test.GetLibVersion(Native Method)
> at Test.main(Test.java:13)
> ```

В чём может быть причина ?

**Страница из описания библиотеки.**

Метод Connect интерфейса ISpRecordClientW

Устанавливает соединение с программой записи.

Синтаксис

```
[Delphi] function Connect(Flags: Integer; const Username: WideString; const Password: WideString): Integer;

[C++] long Connect(long Flags, BSTR Username, BSTR Password);
```

Описание

Метод устанавливает соединение с программой записи. Необходимо вызвать его перед тем как станет возможен вызов других методов интерфейса. Для отключения и освобождения занимаемых ресурсов вызовите метод Disconnect.

Параметры

Flags 
В настоящее время не используется и должен содержать 0. 
Username 
Имя пользователя. В настоящее время не используется и должен содержать пустую строку. 
Password 
Пароль пользователя. В настоящее время не используется и должен содержать пустую строку. 
Возвращаемое значение

Если метод выполнен успешно и подключение установлено, то возвращаемое значение SPR_S_OK. Если подключение уже выполнено, то возвращаемое значение SPR_S_FALSE.

Если подключение выполнить не удалось, то метод возвращает код ошибки:

```
SPR_E_CLIENTSOCKETOPEN
SPR_E_SPRECORDPRGNOTFOUND
SPR_E_ACCESS_DENIED
SPR_E_CONNECT_LIMIT
SPR_E_SOCKETOPEN
SPR_E_LIBVERSION
SPR_E_USERNAMEORPASSWORD
```

Замечания

Для того чтобы подключение было установлено необходимо в главном меню оболочки администрирования выбрать пункт Настройки, в нем подпункт Параметры, на вкладке Общее выбрать вкладку Программа и установить флажок Разрешить подключение библиотеки оповещения.

Допускается не более 1024 одновременных подключений включая подключения интерфейса ISpRecordChannelClientW.

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещен в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/47704/discussion-on-question-by-varg-sieg----------jav).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Скорее всего, вы взяли библиотеку, написанную на C++ и не предназначенную для использования с JNI (Java Native Interface), поэтому ваш простой пример и не работает. Для этого нужно писать еще одну DLL-библиотеку - прослойку JNI, где будет описание в нужном формате экспортируемых функций ([пример использования JNI](https://www3.ntu.edu.sg/home/ehchua/programming/java/JavaNativeInterface.html)).

Собственно, исключение `java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError` и возникает из-за того, что описание нативной функции в формате JNI не найдено.

Как вариант, можно использовать JNA (Java Native Access). JNA позволяет обойтись написанием этой прослойки непосредственно в Java-классе, что существенно проще ([начало работы с JNA](https://github.com/java-native-access/jna/blob/master/www/GettingStarted.md)).

---

Если используемая вами библиотека - сторонняя/покупаемая, то, возможно, разработчик (либо какой-либо энтузиаст) предусмотрел возможность ее использования в Java и может предоставить JNI-интерфейс.